# Get value from Measure in OLAP Cube and Insert it in a SQL table

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, ssas, olap, sql-agent-job

I need help with the the following:

I got an OLAP Cube, let's call it "company_prod" on "server\instance"

That Cube has (among many) a calculated member called "[Measures].[Value]"

One of the Dimensions in the Cube is for time (Year, Month, Date and so on). e.g. [TIME].[Y_M_D].[YEAR].&[2020]

Our main frontend is Excel, where we retrieve Data from the Cube with CUBEELEMENT, CUBEVALUE etc.

We got some measures which unfortunately, when I update the Excel report now and show numbers for last year, the result is different when I update that same report in a few weeks or months. This is something I won't be able to change and in some reports it's the desired behaviour because underlying data from SAP is changed and sometimes valid_from and valid_to dates are changed retroactively.

Now I want to get the value from my "[Measures].[Value]" on a certain date, let's say April 1st. I then want to insert the value I get on April 1st for 2020 in a SQL table. This should be done by an agent job that executes a stored procedure or runs a dtsx package or anything else, whichever works.

I hope it's clear what I am trying to accomplish...

Answer (score 1):

If you can create [linked servers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15) from your SQL Server to SSAS Server, then you can run your MDX query against the linked SSAS Server using [OPENQUERY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openquery-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and save the result directly to the SQL Server table.

i.e.,

```
INSERT INTO <your table>
EXECUTE <your mdx statement> AT <linked server>
```

You can add the run the above via your SQL Agent job on schedule.